# how to convert lambda expression with statement body to an expression tree

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have problem with my code, I don't know problem because am new to c#, But am trying to convert a project from Asp.Net MVC to Core. can someone help me with this code.

```
        using (var context = new UniversityDbContext())
        {
            var  payments =
                (from p in context.Payments
                    .FromSql(
                        "select * from dbo.Payments p inner join dbo.Bills b on p.BillId = b.Id where p.OrderStatus = \'Approved\' order by p.Service")
                 join b in context.Bills on p.BillId equals b.Id
                 where b.User == userId
                 select new { p, b })

            //error is from this   .Select(x =>
                 {
                     x.p.Bill = x.b;
                     return x.p;
                 }).ToList();   // To this

            var t = payments.Count();


            return payments;
        }
```

Comment: Share us your current model defination. For Asp.Net, you could define many-to-many relationship directly. But for asp.net core, you need to define middle class to implement many-to-many relationship. You need to redesign your model.

Answer (score 0):

if Context.Payments.Bills is defined
then you can use the code below

```
  context.Payments.FromSql(
      "select * from dbo.Payments p where p.OrderStatus = 'Approved' order by p.Service").Include(x => x.Bills);
```

needs to return Bills as well inside Payments `p.Bills`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#including-related-data

Answer (score 0):

For `lambda expression with statement body to an expression tree` this issue, you could not pass `x.p.Bill = x.b;` to linq query statement, try something like below:

```
using (var context = new UniversityDbContext())
{
    var  payments =
        (from p in context.Payments
            .FromSql(
                "select * from dbo.Payments p inner join dbo.Bills b on p.BillId = b.Id where p.OrderStatus = \'Approved\' order by p.Service")
            join b in context.Bills on p.BillId equals b.Id
            where b.User == userId
            select new { p, b })
            .ToList()
            .Select(x =>
            {
                x.p.Bill = x.b;
                return x.p;
            }).ToList();   // To this

    var t = payments.Count();
    return payments;
}
```